# Is there any meaning behind the Science Frontiers logo?

Tags: v-1983

In the `V` TV series, Science Frontiers plays an important part. Obviously the Visitors' symbol is intended to be reminiscent of the Nazi symbol; am I also supposed to infer some meaning from the Science Frontiers logo, or was it created just for the TV series?

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit fancy http://99percentinvisible.org/episode/the-fancy-shape/